# Behavior of Nested BeginTransaction calls in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Currently using BeginTransaction() to make changes to my database.

The code for a basic transaction looks like this:

```
using (var ctxTransaction = _db.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        //do A
        _db.SaveChanges()
        ctxTransaction.Commit();
    }
```

but I'm calling a method that also executes a transaction, effectively making my function look like this:

```
using (var ctxTransaction = _db.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        //do A
        _db.SaveChanges()

        using (var ctxTransaction2 = _db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            //do B
            _db.SaveChanges()
            ctxTransaction2.Commit();
        }

        //do C
        _db.SaveChanges()
        ctxTransaction.Commit();
    }
```

1. If B is rolled back, will A also be rolled back?
2. if C is rolled back, will B also be rolled back?

Comment: That will **depend** on the underlying database system you're talking to. Please add a relevant tag for which concrete RDBMS you're using

Comment: Should be simple enough to create a spike and test the behaviour against your selected database, then raise a question if there is an alternative behaviour you are looking for.